# Sample size to compare ' change from baseline' proportions between two groups?

Tags: statistical-power

I have frequencies for variable with answers Yes and NO for two time points (at baseline and after treatment).  The frequencies are recorded for two treatments. I would like to compare the change from baseline between these two treatments. How can I calculate the sample size?

I have the following frequencies for “Yes”:

treatment 1 : 28% at baseline
treatment 1 : 41% after treatment, and

treatment 2 : 21% at baseline
treatment 2 : 39% after treatment.

Comment: You already have the data, what kind of sample size do you want to compute?

Comment: Also, are these paired data, that is the pre-post values are measured for the same subject? If yes, you need some idea about the within-subject correlation.